# Windows 10: Kerberos settings not found

Tags: hardening, windows-10

In our company, we want to configure our Windows-based infrastructure compliant to the *IASE SCAP* [specifications](https://iase.disa.mil/stigs/scap/Pages/index.aspx), e.g., the *Microsoft Windows Server 2016 STIG Benchmark*.
In this document, there is the rule that `Computer Configuration >> Policies >> Windows Settings >> Security Settings >> Account Policies >> Kerberos Policy >> Enforce user logon restrictions` should be `Enabled`.

I've searched for this settings in `Windows Server 2016`, `Windows 10 Education`, `Windows 10 Enterprise`, and `Windows 10 Pro` and it was nowhere visible ....

[image]

What do I have to activate or enable to see the `Kerberos Policies`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enforce user logon restrictions` is a setting that only applies to domain controllers, not workstations or member servers. Only domain controllers issue Kerberos tickets.

`What do I have to activate or enable to see the Kerberos Policies?`

Enable the setting in the Default Domain Controllers Policy. (It's enabled by default). Run `gpresult /h gpresult.html` on a domain controller to view the settings.